# PHP Code to Twig Code

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, twig

Recently a programmer converted my Wordpress templates to Twig code and I'm not quite sure from looking at the code how I would write the following examples out in Twig code. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you so much!

```
<?php if ( $post->post_date >= date("2003-07-15 00:00:00") && $post->post_date <= date("2004-07-17 23:59:59")) { ?>

<?php } elseif ( $post->post_date >= date("2004-12-23 00:00:00") && $post->post_date <= date("2005-07-16 23:59:59")) { ?>

<?php } else { ?><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig is a template engine. You should do most if not all of the processing with PHP.
Only then you pass the processed data to Twig as a variable.

For example, you can do something like this.

PHP

```
<?php
$data['posts'] = array('type' => 0, 'post' => '');

if ( $post->post_date >= date("2003-07-15 00:00:00") && $post->post_date <= date("2004-07-17 23:59:59")) {
    $data['posts'][] = array('type' => 1, 'post' => $post);
} elseif ( $post->post_date >= date("2004-12-23 00:00:00") && $post->post_date <= date("2005-07-16 23:59:59")) {
    $data['posts'][] = array('type' => 2, 'post' => $post);
} else { $data['posts'][] = array('type' => 0, 'post' => $post); }
?>
```

Twig

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if post['type'] == 1 %}
    $post->post_date >= date("2003-07-15 00:00:00") && $post->post_date <= date("2004-07-17 23:59:59") goes here
  {% elseif post['type'] == 2 %}
    $post->post_date >= date("2004-12-23 00:00:00") && $post->post_date <= date("2005-07-16 23:59:59") goes here
  {% else %}
    Everything else goes here
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I'm understanding how this works a little better. But do you know where I would put the PHP portion of the code? Is there a specific file I place it in? Thank you.

Comment: Any .php file you want, really but that will be the WordPress part.
[WordPress Template File List](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List)

It might be a good idea to modify the theme you're using or if you're developing a theme, that will be it.